# Generate key press from hardware level and capture the output using Python

Tags: python

I am writing an automation test for a hotkey application and one of the challenges is to find out if the correct key/s are pressed after remapping a key. For example, if I rebind the Q key to A, the letter A should type in when I press Q in the keyboard.

Now, I want to be able to perform this action through a script without having to manually press the rebinded key. I have tried the libraries pywinauto, keyboard, and pynput to no avail; they just type in the exact character/s and no conversion occurs.

How to reproduce:

1. rebind Q key to A using any hotkey software (using any remapping/hotkey tool e.g. autohotkey, razer synapse, logitech setpoint, microsoft mouse and keyboard center, etc.)
2. install python keyboard library https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/
3. run below in python console

> ```
> >>> import keyboard
> >>> keyboard.press_and_release('Q')
> >>> Q
> ```

In the above, Q was rebinded to A in the hotkey application but the code still outputted Q.

Is it possible to send actual key press events as though the physical buttons are pressed (so that the hotkey is triggered) and Q will type A instead? And to capture the key press (A) and store it in a string so that I can use this to assert whether the hotkey is activated. The code should work regardless of what hotkey program I use to rebind a key.

Comment: Perhaps you should not send a "Q" but a scancode instead.

Comment: The libraries I mentioned above only accepts plain characters as arguments to their respective keypress methods.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added reproduction steps

Comment: As @ThomasWeller says, you need to generate keyboard scancodes (which is what the keyboard produces) __and__ feed them into the hotkey application as though they come from the actual physical keyboard.

Comment: @barny I'm not sure what you mean, these hotkey apps don't allow you to set scan codes to bind to a key, your regular user won't have any idea about what scan codes are.